# API for getting list of nameservers used in system

Tags: c, linux, unix, libc, resolver

Is there a way (API) to get list of nameservers on Linux except of well known res_(n)init?

options:

- use of .nscount and .nsaddr_list[] after res_(n)init() call
- parsing resolv.conf on your own
- ???

trying to find a more-less portable way to get NSes

Comment: I don't think there's any useful way of getting this information, because these days you don't know where that information is actually stored. `/etc/resolv.conf` may point at a localhost address, which could be something like dnsmasq or systemd-resolved, each with its own mechanism for storing configuration.

Comment: With .nsaddr_list[] after res_[n]init() it works (almost) everywhere. Systemd-resolved writes out local NS in the same /etc/resolv.conf, that's enough to get it after res_init() call. With dnsmasq I suppose it something like that.

Comment: mostly interested in the case if there's other API like res_init() to get NSes from resolv.conf not parsing it like a text (with which software that file is written it's not principally).

Comment: systemd-resolved does **not** necessarily write out information to `/etc/resolv.conf`. It's common that `resolv.conf` contains only `namesever 127.0.0.53` and never changes. In other words, the solution you've proposed works for only a certain number of specific situations, and is likely to not work in others. Whether or not this matters depends on the scope of where you're deploying it.

Comment: Any guaranteed working NS[es] (a local on loopback or remote ones, it doesn't matter) is enough, and it _already_ works in all those systems that I've been working. It's not a question about how to get NSes written in systemd-resolved conf or those from caching named, etc. That's only about NSes from resolv.conf.

Comment: What systems do you care about, where res_(n)init doesn't work well enough for your purposes? Also, why do you need this information?

Comment: @zwol it's functional of libc, the last times started to pop up new ones. So far only seen libc with nscount=0 (and corresponding nsaddr_list[]) is musl (on linux). Maybe in future there will be more, who knows.